# File Object is Empty after performing Copy to DB using Psycopg2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, postgresql, psycopg2

In the below example contents of the file seems to become empty after performing copy_expert command and pd.read_csv is throwing an error stating it is an empty file. The file seems to be empty even when I performing this operation in reverse order (read_csv before copy_expert). Why is file empty and how can I handle this scenario?

```
    file = //download file from S3

    copy_sql = """
                   COPY %s FROM stdin WITH CSV HEADER
                   DELIMITER as ','
                   """
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
    cursor.copy_expert(sql=copy_sql % table_name, file=file)
    cursor.close()

   df = pd.read_csv(file, dtype={// dtype value})
```

**EDIT**

I was able to solve it by performing following , however it would be helpful to understand why the file object is emptied and also if there is a more efficient way of doing this.

```
    file = //download file from S3
    file_clone = copy.deepcopy(file)
    copy_sql = """
                   COPY %s FROM stdin WITH CSV HEADER
                   DELIMITER as ','
                   """
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
    cursor.copy_expert(sql=copy_sql % table_name, file=file)
    cursor.close()

   df = pd.read_csv(file_clone, dtype={// dtype value})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that after **first** reading the file data, the `file pointer` will be at the end of the file; the subsequent read call will return no data.
In order to be able to read the data again you need to move the pointer to the beginning of the file:

```py
cursor.copy_expert(sql=copy_sql % table_name, file=file)
file.seek(0)
df = pd.read_csv(file, dtype={// dtype value})
```